# Is Hulu's M.O.D.O.K. part of the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, modok-2021

Hulu is releasing an animated TV show called [*"Marvel's M.O.D.O.K."*](https://press.hulu.com/shows/m-o-d-o-k/). It is being produced by Marvel Studios, and Hulu is part of the greater Disney family, which houses MCU content.

However, currently all MCU shows (e.g. WandaVision, Falcon and the Winter Soldier, Loki, etc.) have been released on Disney+. Although I wouldn't put it past the bean counters to release another show on another service just to drive subscription rates. Also, the show is animated, not live action, which would set it apart from other MCU features.

So, has Kevin Feige (or some other MCU executive) spoken about whether M.O.D.O.K. is part of the "official MCU", or just a fun Marvel creation on its own?

Comment: Not just animated, but stop-motion; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSEWdhHBlYU

Comment: Isn’t _What If?_, at least, going to be animated? It’s not inconceivable that it being animated would mean it’s not in the MCU.

Comment: Or to give it its full title, _Disney's Hulu's Marvel's M.O.D.O.K.'s Hulu's Kevin's Marvel's Hulu's Disney's M.O.D.O.K.'s Animated Content Unit #1226-D23._

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Marvel's [*M.O.D.O.K*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.O.D.O.K._(TV_series)) exists in a 'numbered reality'. There's nothing to stop the MCU from using elements from that (now that they're acknowledging the existence of other universes), but the likelihood of a canon crossover is quite low.

> Premiering May 21 on Hulu (not Disney+), M.O.D.O.K. isn't technically
> part of the Marvel Cinematic Universe. At least not yet.
>
> “Our show was given its own numbered reality,” Blum says. “We are
> Earth-1226, which is my son’s birthday. We are **canonically part of the
> Marvel multiverse**, and it’s up to them if they want to bridge us or
> not.”
>
> <sub><sup>['M.O.D.O.K.' SHOWRUNNER REVEALS HOW AN MCU CROSSOVER COULD HAPPEN](https://www.inverse.com/entertainment/modok-hulu-multiverse-mcu-jordan-blum)</sup></sub>

Comment: Very cool! We know the MCU is barreling into the multiverse from WandaVision and the not so subtly titled "Dr. Strange and the Multiverse of Madness"

Comment: <insert>well_yes_but_actually_no_meme</>